# System.net.Sockets exception

Tags: c#, mysql, virtual-machine

So I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database sitting on an Ubuntu VM using C#. However, I keep getting a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` exception and the connection fails every time. I can access the server on the VM using it's IP address (on a browser) so I'm not really understanding whats wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Exceptions come with messages.

Comment: You mentioned you can access the ip address in a browser, this might be a silly question connecting to the ip address through a browser doesn't preclude the port being closed that is needed for the socket to connect to. Just to cross the t's and don't the i's make sure the port you have configured for mysql is open on ubuntu and any other firewall that sits between you're client and it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try telnet to the mysql server from where you are trying to connect,`telnet localhost 3306` localhost is your mysql server and 3306 is default port. If this is successful then it means that mysql is running correctly. Also you can verify if the credentials are passed correctly. Below is sample JNDI configuration for connecting to mysql from liferay portal server

```
<Resource name="jdbc/LiferayPool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
     username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liferay?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useFastDateParsing=false"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, when i use telnet localhost 3306,it says :
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1/UKUM^rE�K<+_}w`Xz~*Smysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is ok you may try the ADO.Net driver for MySQL (http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

After you install the driver, add a reference to MySql.Data.dll in you project.

In your code, you can connect to the server using:

```
public static MySqlConnection mysqlCreateConection() {            
        try {
            c = new MySqlConnection("server=" + "localhost" + ";user id=" + "user" +
                                    ";Password=" + "password" + ";persist security info=True;database=" + mysqlDatabase +  "" + ";");
            c.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
            return c;
        } catch (MySqlException e) {}
```

With this connector you can use classes and methods already made to make your life easier when dealing with c# + mysql.

Comment: Hey i tried out your code, and added user@<myipaddress> to the allowed list of users at mysql, but it still continues to give me the same error. Any ideas whats going on?